# Number of homomorphic images of a cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ is the number of divisors of $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that the Number of homomorphic images of a cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ is the number of divisors of $n$

**Attempt:** If $\phi : G \mapsto G'$ is a homomorphism, then if $\phi(g) = g'$ where $g \in G,~ g' \in G'$, then :

$\phi^{-1}(g') = g ~Ker (~\phi) .........(1)$

We know that $Ker (~\phi)$ forms a subgroup of $G$ and every subgroup of $G$ will be cyclic since $G$ is cyclic. Hence $Ker (~\phi)$ shall also be a cyclic subgroup.

Also, $\phi(g_1) = \phi(g_2)$

$ => g_1 ~Ker (~\phi) = g_2 ~Ker (~\phi) ~\forall~ g_1,g_2~\in G .......(2)$

Hence, the number of distinct homomorphic images of $\phi =$ Number of distinct Cosets of $ Ker (~\phi) = |G|/|Ker (~\phi)| = n/|Ker (~\phi)|$

How can this be equal to the number of divisors of $n$?

Help shall be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Other approach: every homomorphic image is determined by a quotient of $G$ by normal subgroup $N$, $G/N$. So you are done if you know all (normal) subgroups of the cyclic $G$.

Comment: Every subgroup of cyclic $G$ shall be cyclic and normal. So, the number of such subgroups is number of divisors of $n$. Hence, the result .

But, how do we prove that every homomorphic image is determined by a quotient of G by normal subgroup $N, G/N$. I mean can't there be any more homomorphisms not determined by $N$?

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @VDH - yes exactly, this boils down to the number of subgroups of $G$ and that equals the number of divisors of $G$. Now apply the 1st isomorphism theorem: $G/ker(\phi) \cong im(\phi)$. Every homomorphic image arises in this way!

Comment: In your attempt you are confusing "images of $\phi$" (that is "distinct images $\phi(g)$" as $g$ ranges over $G$), with "homomorphic images of $G$", which typically involve DIFFERENT homomorphisms.

Comment: In the case of cyclic groups, every subgroup is normal, and only 1 subgroup exists for a given order which also divides the order of the group. [Every normal subgroup is the kernal of a Homomorphism](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup_equals_kernel_of_homomorphism). The image will be $G/N$ just like @nicky mentioned.

Comment: Got it. Thank you everyone for your answers :)